# Directory path string comes with "\\" and causing error

Tags: directory, path

I have 2 computers which languages are different. My C# program runs without problem in EN computer. But in other TR computer the string of directory's path gives error because of it adds extra `"\"` to string. Herebelow is my code.

`string pathway = @"D:\test\subtest"`  but VS compiles it as  `D:\\test\\subtest`

I also tried that path without @ sign  `D:\\test\\subtest`  but nothing changed. Can someone assist me please since I have no idea where to look and what to change.